# How to add reaction force to a collision in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

So when using rigidbody physics on a 2d sphere and a spinning animated 2d rectangle it only pushes the sphere aside when it collides. What I'm wanting is the sphere to fly off when collided (don't ask if it's if it's a problem with it colliding or not).

I've tried the physics materials and adjusting the rigidbody and such but nothing works. There's not a single thing online about it so attempting to code physics would be very difficult.

Comment: I don't know Unity well, but if you want a sudden injection of force/momentum that's roughly an explosion. And I expect Unity can do explosions on impact, and can make your spinning rectangle immune so that only the sphere is affected by the point explosion.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly.

You could apply [AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html) or [AddForceAtPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForceAtPosition.html) function with [ForceMode.Impulse](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.Impulse.htm) argument to sphere when `Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D)` event trigger.

Or Just modify sphere speed when `Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D)` event trigger.

Note that [Collision2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D.html) have `contacts` and `relativeVelocity` which may help you calc the force vector.

Comment: Okay thanks, so what direction would the force be applied to the sphere as the first argument of AddForce is the direction? If it was a forward-backward motion then it would be more easier to get the direction but I'm not sure about a spinning one

Comment: @TrashMachine maybe you could use relativeVelocity  in Collision2D.